# How can I keep running a loop until the key is pressed (C++)

Tags: c++, macos, console-application, keyboard-input

I know this question has been asked several times on the net, but I could not find any of those answers helpful.

I want to keep running a loop and break it once the user press a key (e.g. `enter` or `esc`). I don't want it to ask user any input *during* the process.

I have a `while` loop.

I am new to C++, so please answer simply.

My system is Mac OS X.

Comment: when run from the command line, the user can press ctrl+C to end a program

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: @Crazyman135790: How would that information improve this question?

Comment: Something like this is OS dependent.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley any info would help.

Comment: I think you need more than 1 thead, one to run the loop and second to capture the event and modify a property. You could check the value of property to exit out of loop.

Comment: @Crazyman135790: No, not any info would help. For example, information about what he had for breakfast wouldn't help. And that was not meant to be sarcastic or snarky, just an example of a piece of information that wouldn't improve the question. And I suggest that information about what he tried also lies in that category.

Comment: Sorry folks. none of your comments does not work for me.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a single operating system or compiler. It can be a set of them. There are libraries that will abstract over the differences. e.g. multimedia libraries like SFML or SDL, or gui libraries like Qt or wxWidgets. Or libraries dedicated specifically to input, like OIS.

Comment: @Mr.Singh Using threads of C++11 might indeed work in plain C++11...

Comment: @ user3720389 Do you know how to capture  programmatically   user's action of  pressing  key, please share that?

Comment: You could use signals to catch a Ctrl-C, or use something non-standard to grab key states in conjunction with threading...

Comment: @hyde I am using Mac OS X, and Xcode.

Comment: @user3720389 Tag your question with that information.

Comment: @user3720389 I edited tags. I assumed you are doing a console application. If you in fact have GUI app, please fix the tags!

Comment: @ hyde thanks. No, I don't have GUI.

Comment: Have a look at the documentation for NSEvent, this might lead you down the right path for grabbing key-states. This is not C++ but Objective-C++ however... Given that you say you are new, maybe take a step back and look for a simpler solution to yield the result you want?

Answer (score 2):

There you go. I hope this helps.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>

// A flag to indicate whether a key had been pressed.
atomic_bool keyIsPressed(false);

// The function that has the loop.
void loopFunction()
{
    while (!keyIsPressed) {
        // Do whatever
    }
}

// main
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    // Create a thread for the loop.
    thread loopThread = thread(loopFunction);
    // Wait for user input (single character). This is OS dependent.
#ifdef _WIN32 || _WIN64
    system("pause");
#else
    system("read -n1");
#endif
    // Set the flag with true to break the loop.
    keyIsPressed = true;
    // Wait for the thread to finish.
    loopThread.join();

    // Done.
    return 0;
}
```

**Update:** Since the flag `keyIsPressed` is shared between threads, I added `atomic` for that. Thanks to @hyde.

Comment: You could make this standard by using fgetc(stdin)

Comment: Umm... Using `system()` to pause? Why not `getchar()` or `std::cin`?

Comment: Also you should note that this is C++11, so OP will need to use the -std=c++11 flag

Comment: You're right. It will work too. However, `getchar` and `std::cin` requires an `enter` press. The others won't. They'll continue as soon as the user presses any key. Just in case it's needed.

Comment: At least make `keyIsPressed` an atomic. Otherwise optimizations or multiple CPUs or whatnot may prevent other thread from seeing the change in its value.

Comment: @hyde Correct. Thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed OS dependent, but probabilities are that you use Windows.

First, you'll need to include :

```
#include <Windows.h>
```

It gives you access to the function GetAsyncKeyState, and to Windows' key macros [(list of Windows' key macros)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx).

You'll also need the Most Significant Bit to evaluate key press ; just initialize it as a const in your code :

```
const unsigned short MSB = 0x8000;
```

Finally, let's put all together in a function :

```
bool listenKeyPress(short p_key)
{
    //if p_key is pushed, the MSB will be set at 1
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(p_key) & MSB)
    {
        return true;
    }

    else return false;
}

//Example of a call to this function to check if up enter is pressed :
listenKeyPress(VK_RETURN)
```

Then your while loop can be typed either :

```
while (!listenKeyPress(VK_ENTER))
{
}
```

or

```
bool quit = false;
while (!quit)
{
    if (listenKeyPress(VK_ENTER) || listenKeyPress(VK_ESCAPE)
        quit = true;
}
```

There you go!

Comment: Thank you, however, I am using Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Was curious myself how to do this when started... turns out never really used it was better to just getch() but if you need this and using windows include `Windows.h` and the following code should point you in the right direction (hopefully)

```
bool f = true;
    while (f)
    {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP)){
            //Enter code for when a button is pushed here
            f = false;
        }
        else{
            //Code to run until the button is pushed
        }
    }
```

If you want to use a different button VK_UP can be changed to any key or mouse button you have, just scroll through the list(assuming you are probably a student using visual studio) if you have no list look up what key applies for the button you wish to press.

EDIT: Also if you want it to run forever remove the f = false and it will work while button is pressed and while not pressed to do whatever you like (Not great coding practice to leave no exit of a while loop though so probably best to test for a key being pressed in another while loop to exit)